# Storing comments with mysql

Tags: mysql

Whats the common approach here?

Make a new table per every commentable thing - not sure if good idea, unfamiliar with overhead resulting from this but I suspect there is some.

Make one bigass table with every single comment in it - I'd have to select where an ID matches, that sounds like a search, an expensive one! Or can mysql make a hash tables for keys to speed it up?

Make medium sized tables? Like an in-between option.. lets say every table contains the comments of 1000 items so for 30k items, I'd have 30 tables?

No wonder a lot of sites with commenting fetch the comments later when necessary :o

Comment: By "comments", you mean entities that represent a comment, right?

Comment: The main premise of the question, which is "storing a bunch of comments in a database", is too broad to broach; there's a billion ways to go about doing this.  My belief is that your question lies with how databases interact with software, which is why you first believed that you need a lot of tables for this (most implementations, like [`acts_as_commentable_with_threading`](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading) just use *one* table).  Before you could appreciate an answer to this question, I would encourage you to read up on databases and database design.

Answer (score 2):

In a most simple way comments is something like this:

Comments

id | Parent | Author | Comment | Other fields

If you need something more complicated then you will have to think through it.

Don't think about premature optimization. Modern databases can handle enormous amount of data very well.